# Add a dataset to my Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal report on my project and I want to add a new table to my DataSet. I created the table and I open the Dataset Expert dialog. When I choose the new table to Add it shows me another dialog where I have to write the name of my Class. If I don't to that it gaves me an error called "Logon failed".

Which class do I have to especify?

Can you  help me?

Thank you.